# Variable Array based on cell value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

The following code shows an array with fixed size, with six values.

What should I do to make its size depends on a cell value? For example, from 1 to 10?

```
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
        Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
   MySlideArray = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
 'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from. For now, assume that it's always 6 ranges
  With tb.DataBodyRange
     MyRangeArray = Array(Worksheets(.Cells(1, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(1, 2).Value), _
                Worksheets(.Cells(2, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(2, 2).Value), _
                Worksheets(.Cells(3, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(3, 2).Value), _
                Worksheets(.Cells(4, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(4, 2).Value), _
                Worksheets(.Cells(5, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(5, 2).Value), _
                Worksheets(.Cells(6, 1).Value).Range(.Cells(6, 2).Value))



'Loop through Array data
For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
'Copy Excel Range
MyRangeArray(x).Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 'Excel 2007-2010
    Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'Excel 2013
  On Error GoTo 0]
```

Comment: are you meaning `redim` and/or `redim preserve`?

Comment: I tried that! but didnt work out. i used the following: [code] Dim Max as INteger Max = Sheets("Home").Range("H1").Value ReDim MySlideArray(2 To Max) [code], but did not work out. got error 91 in another line, above all these

Comment: by `redim myslidearray(2 to max)` you are saying you want an array with `max - 2` slots with a `lbound` of 2 and a `ubound` of max not an array with values 2 to max. So in the code you are calling `myslidearray(2) to `myslidearray(max) which does not exist the `MyRangeArray`  with a `lbound` of 1 and a `ubound` of 5

Comment: thanks for your answer! how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReDim`

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim myArr() As Range
    Dim myCell

    Set myCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    ReDim myArr(0 To myCell.Value)

    Debug.Print LBound(myArr), UBound(myArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that! but didnt work out. i used the following:   [code] Dim Max as INteger  Max = Sheets("Home").Range("H1").Value  ReDim MySlideArray(2 To Max) [code], but did not work out. got error 91 in another line, above all these

Comment: You should *edit your question* and show exactly what you tried, and describe exactly what happened when you ran it.